# "Serial attribute not found" in python

Tags: python, pyserial

I am trying to use a numato USB relay, but keep getting an error with the serial module.

```
serPort = serial.Serial(portName, 19200, timeout=1)
```

I keep getting the error `"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Serial'"` I have seen many people online with the same problem, but the only solution I saw was that they had saved a file as `serial.py`. I have not done that. Changing "import serial" to "from serial import serial" gives me `"ImportError: cannot import name serial"`. I have also tried both python 2.7 and python 3.6.

I would love some help figuring out how to get my USB relay to work.

Comment: First serial not support python3.6, second call `python` always returned default version of python.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall `serial` and install `pyserial` using:

```
python -m pip uninstall serial
python -m pip install pyserial
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have commented to T HareesH but im new to stack.

Just wanted to say I had this same problem. tried

`import serial`
and

```
import serial from serial
```

but received error
ImportError: cannot import name serial

but then uninstalled serial and installed pyserial

```
python -m pip uninstall serial
python -m pip install pyserial
```

and made the script like this and it worked

```
import tkinter, time, pyfirmata, sys
import serial

pinG = 12

strComPort = 'COM7'
strComBaud = 9600

brdUno = pyfirmata.Arduino(strComPort)

#brdUno.PWM
brdUno.digital[pinG].write(1)
time.sleep(3)
brdUno.digital[pinG].write(0)

brdUno.exit()
```

and it worked! I am interfacing python IDE on win10 with an Arduino Uno